# Can't push to heroku - sqlite3.h is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

first post here =) Thanks in advance for helping out, any help is cool at this point!

1- I've searched quite a lot and tried loads of stuff before considering posting on stackoverflow..

2- When running

```
   git push heroku master
```

I get this:

```
   checking for sqlite3.h... no
   sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
   or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
   location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
```

3- I checked the Gemfile: production and dev/test are well configured for pg and sqlite3 respectively

4- Sqlite3.h is here:

```
   pcbo$ ls -l /usr/include/sqlite3.h
   -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  322724  7 Dec  2011 /usr/include/sqlite3.h
```

5- Forgot to mention i'm using mac os x..

6- Output of:
        pcbo$ git push heroku master

```
    Counting objects: 71, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (71/71), 26.46 KiB, done.
    Total 71 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)

    -----> Heroku receiving push
    -----> Ruby/Rails app detected
    -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0.pre
    Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
   Installing rake (0.9.2.2)
   Installing i18n (0.6.0)
   Installing multi_json (1.3.6)
   Installing activesupport (3.2.3)
   Installing builder (3.0.0)
   Installing activemodel (3.2.3)
   Installing erubis (2.7.0)
   Installing journey (1.0.3)
   Installing rack (1.4.1)
   Installing rack-cache (1.2)
   Installing rack-test (0.6.1)
   Installing hike (1.2.1)
   Installing tilt (1.3.3)
   Installing sprockets (2.1.3)
   Installing actionpack (3.2.3)
   Installing mime-types (1.18)
   Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
   Installing treetop (1.4.10)
   Installing mail (2.4.4)
   Installing actionmailer (3.2.3)
   Installing arel (3.0.2)
   Installing tzinfo (0.3.33)
   Installing activerecord (3.2.3)
   Installing activeresource (3.2.3)
   Installing coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
   Installing execjs (1.4.0)
   Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
   Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
   Installing json (1.7.3) with native extensions
   Installing rdoc (3.12)
   Installing thor (0.14.6)
   Installing railties (3.2.3)
   Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
   Installing jquery-rails (2.0.2)
   Installing pg (0.12.2) with native extensions
   Using bundler (1.2.0.pre)
   Installing rails (3.2.3)
   Installing sass (3.1.19)
   Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
   Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for sqlite3.h... no
   sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
   or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
   location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
   --with-sqlite3-dir
   --without-sqlite3-dir
   --with-sqlite3-include
   --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
   --with-sqlite3-lib
   --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
   --enable-local
   --disable-local
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_zmjrcoagwpai/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_zmjrcoagwpai/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
   !
   !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
   !
   !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

7- Any help is really appreciated !

Comment: Is that `ls -l` output from your local development machine or the Heroku machine that will run your software?

Comment: @sarnold: it's my local dev machine

Comment: @ismaelga: I removed all references to sqlite3 from Gemfile.lock - keeps happening: "sqlite3.h is missing"

Comment: I removed that comment because I think it actually dons't make any difference. Unless to check if there are any gem in production that depends on sqlite.

Comment: @ismaelga no worries i got it. Yes, **in the very beginning** i followed this tutorial and used the command `heroku create --stack cedar`: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec:heroku_commands

Comment: Did you commit the new Gemfile* files after making changes too them, before doing the new git push?

Comment: @JonMountjoy that was exactly the problem. Thanks for you help!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[Update1]**

From your git push log, Here is your culprit:-

```
 Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions
```

So, As I initially suspected, blunder is trying to load `sqlite3` gem which WILL fail on heroku. as said earlier this can happen because of two reasons

1. Gemfile is wrongly configured to require sqlite3 gem in production
2. Some other gem has dependency on `sqlite3` gem. use the `gem dependency` command to show the dependencies of gem & remove that gem which depends on `sqlite3`.

After that, rerun `bundle install` & it would work.

---[End Update1]---

The only reason you can get this error is when, trying to use `sqlite3` database on heroku which is not supported.  so closely inspect your `Gemfile` and make sure its setup similar to this

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

And then do `bundle install` to regenerate your `Gemfile.lock`. now, try to push heroku. if you still get this error, then probably some gem that you are using has listed `sqlite3` as hard-coded dependency in its `gemspec` file. so in effect, sqlite3 is being loaded even though its not present in gemfile. so verify this, run the following command on localhost:

```
$ bundle install | grep sqlite
```

Lastly, after trying this. it doesn't work. Post back the **complete** log of `git push heroku master` & output of `heroku logs`.

Comment: Hi @Gaurish. as I mentioned before the Gemfile was correctly configured and the `bundle install | grep sqlite` returns `Using sqlite3 (1.3.6)`


_Checking right now how to retrieve the heroku logs_

Comment: **Heroku logs:**
2012-06-12T00:53:42+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-06-12T00:54:09+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/rails app
2012-06-12T09:20:31+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-06-12T09:21:04+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/rails app

_is this the logs you asked for?_ Doesn't give much info..

Comment: The log of `git push heroku master` is in the original question (step 6)

Comment: I get this when doing `pcbo$ gem dependency sqlite3
Gem sqlite3-1.3.6
  hoe (~> 3.0, development)
  mini_portile (~> 0.2.2, development)
  rake-compiler (~> 0.7.0, development)
  rdoc (~> 3.10, development)

Gem sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3
  hoe (>= 2.8.0, development)
  sqlite3 (>= 1.3.3)`

Is it normal to have two sqlite ?

Comment: @Gaurish... I forgot to do add the changes to git and, therefore, nothing was happening. Problem solved :) Thanks for being so helpful!

Comment: The git changes were exactly what the problem was for me.

Comment: thanks Gaurish Sharma
It worked very well. The only thing I did after bundle install is
git commit -am "changed Gemfile"
then I did
git push heroku master worked like a charm. thank you so much
Spencer

Comment: I ran into this because I...forgot to merge the branch I was on before committing. Argh! Leaving a note here in case it happens to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the sqlite library is missing.
Try and find it with

```
whereis sqlite3.h
```

If it is in your system, try:

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby -- --with-sqlite3-include=<"url where it is(for eg: /usr/include)">
```

Regards